# Wanted: cloud service that builds my open source project (for free?)

Tags: linux, cloud, dailybuilds

I have a C++ open source project that's available from a public svn repository.

It would help me a lot if there is an online service that I can point to my repository and have it build it with GCC on 32 and 64 bit. Then I know that it builds without errors or warnings.

Running my unit tests would be really nice, but I don't really expect anyone does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenSUSE Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/)?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately for me, my code implements a compression standard that depends on a patent. Projects like this are excluded for legal reasons by opensuse.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)? It is a CI tool where you build, test and deploy your applications. You have also the possibility to use Jenkins as a Service, where you don't need to install, neither to configure anything. There is a PaaS which provides Jenkins as a Service and they also have a free tier where you can build your applications. There are more     specialised on Java but taking a look to their [documentation](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/C+and+C+++Builds), it seems like if you can also build C and C++ applications.